# Reduce compact map time Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using compact map to get models (NSObject) from a json array [[String: Any]].

I made some tests and seems that it takes some time to get my objects from json array. It's about 1 sec for 300 objects in json array.

The problem is that i am dealing with a big app data and i can have thousands of objects in json array.

```
class ModelObject: NSObject {
    var data: Data?
    var json: [String: Any]?

    init(withJSON json: [String: Any]?) {
        data = json?.toData
        self.json = json
    }

    init(withId id: String? = nil,
         withType type: String? = nil,
         withStatus status: Int? = nil,
         withName name: String? = nil) {
        super.init()
        updateContent(withId: id,
                      withType: type,
                      withStatus: status,
                      withName: name)
    }

    func updateContent(withJSON json: [String: Any]? = nil,
                       withId id: String? = nil,
                       withType type: String? = nil,
                       withStatus status: Int? = nil,
                       withName name: String? = nil) {
        var json = self.json ?? [String: Any]()

        if let id = id {
            json["_id"] = id
        }

        if let type = type {
            json["type"] = type
        }

        if let status = status {
            json["status"] = status
        }

        if let name = name {
            json["name"] = name
        }
    }
}

extension Dictionary {
    var toData: Data? {
        return try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: [])
    }
}
```

It's there any other possibility to reduce time or to get it instantly? 
This is my code:

```
return fileJSONArray.compactMap { ModelObject(withJSON: $0) }
```

Comment: You should shared your `ModelObject`.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to see my ModelObject content?

Comment: Maybe you should use `Codable` for decoding json

Comment: Yes, you should share that because you could be performing intensive tasks while creating the `ModelObject`, have you considered using `Codable` as that may be more performant,

Comment: I updated my question adding the ModelObject content.

Comment: `data = json?.toData   self.json = json`, this means your model holds two versions of the same data which seems completely unnecessary. Why do you need `data`, it would probably be better to do the encoding once you actually needs to access your json as `Data`

Comment: `init(withJSON:)` does not return an Optional. Why are you using `compactMap` rather than `map` here? That's forcing it to promote everything to an `ModelObject?` and then demote back to an `ModelObject`. (Also agreed with Joakim; I suspect almost all the cost here is in the re-serialization, which is very expensive, and very unclear why you're doing it.)

Comment: (Also agree with Joakim on the fact that `[String: Any]` and JSONSerialization are horrible to work with in Swift. You really want to convert this to Codable and use properties rather than `[String: Any]`. Similarly working with JSON internally, which you seem to be doing is very inefficient and the code becomes a mess. You just want to convert to JSON when you need to talk to the outside world, and convert from JSON when you receive data. Inside your app, there should be almost no JSON at all, and most data should just be in simple structs. You'll avoid a ton of problems that way.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code that is working is more suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com